# Zurb Foundation 4: Getting error in Reveal - $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am not so much expert in jQuery and still learning.

I am creating WordPress theme using Zurb Framework 4 and trying to add multiple popups using reveal. Everything is works fine without any issue but when I check console than I realized it's giving an error like below

`TypeError: $ is not a function ...'#social-sales, #footer-brochure, #footer-contact').foundation('reveal', 'open',...`

So my code is something like below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // popup boxs
    $('#social-sales, #footer-brochure, #footer-contact').foundation('reveal', 'open', {
        animation: 'fadeAndPop',
        animationSpeed: 100
    });

});
```

When I tried to use `jQuery` than it is behaving weird. On page loads all popups getting open and when closed getting dark overlay background and so on..

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a more generic initialization? Calling `jQuery(document).foundation('reveal', { animationSpeed: 100 });` should do what you want.

Comment: @giaour Yes I did but its not working. Please refer my comment after my reference code in question.

Comment: I meant to ask if you've tried initializing foundation on a more generic *element*. I think `reveal` needs to be initialized on the `document` element.